# Are there any technique for using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove continuous for multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I feel I have lots of trouble with using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove the continuity for multivariable function. The difficult at here is to build up an inequality that allow me to substitute $ \sqrt{(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2}< δ.$ into it, so that I could find a bound for $\delta$.

For example, take a relative simple function $f(x,y) =\frac{x^2}{y}$

Then we let $\epsilon >0 $ be given
$$ \left|\frac{x^2}{y}-\frac{a^2}{b}\right|<\epsilon$$
$$ \left|\frac{x^2b-a^2y}{yb}\right|<\epsilon$$
Then, I am lost at here, I don't know what should I do next, I couldn't substitute $ \sqrt{(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2}< δ$ into the inequality. Could someone help me?

Comment: For your own sanity, I recommend using the $\varepsilon-\delta$-definition as sparingly as possible. In this case, you should use that multiplying and dividing continuous functions yields continuous functions. Then you only have to show that $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ are continuous, which is significantly easier.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos This sounds a good idea, by separating into two functions, I am  actually dealing with two single variable cases. But it that true for quotient rule can apply to this case? What I am warry about is that if I separate to two function I have one function continuous with respect to x, and other one continuous with respect to y. Would the quotient rule still hold since two functions are with respect to two different variables?

Comment: There is a simple lemma that if $f,g:X\to\mathbb R$ are continuous functions, where $X$ is a metric space, then $f\cdot g$ is continuous. Similarly, if additionally $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in X$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is continuous. This lemma doesn't care about the exact nature of $X$ or $f$ and $g$. All it needs is for $X$ to be a metric space, and for $f$ and $g$ to be continuous. Don't let yourself be confused by multiple variables or anything. The nature of continuity couldn't care less about how many variables are used to describe the metric space.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Ok, I see, since $f(x)=x$, and $g(y) =y$ are both function mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so we are fine. But does this lemma  hold if $f, g$ are mapping from different metric space?

Comment: Yes, I said metric space, not $\mathbb R$. It holds for all metric spaces. And no, $f,g$ are not functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. They are functions $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. They just don't depend on both components of the pair $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$. Here, $\mathbb R^2$ is the metric space in question.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, Sorry I am getting a little bit confuse at here. So If I have two continuous function are both defined over $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ but with respect to different variables, than product be continuous does not hold. For the product to be continuous for the new function $h(x,y) =f(x)\cdot g(y)$ over  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I must have functions  $f(x,y)=x$ and $g(x,y)=y$ over $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, even in this case we just have a single input for $f,g$?

Comment: The lemma holds in the first case, too, but only with a little detour. You can prove that the maps $\pi_1,\pi_2:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R,~\pi_1(x,y)=x,~\pi_2(x,y)=y$ are both continuous. So if $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are continuous, then $f\circ\pi_1$ and $g\circ\pi_2$ are continuous, and then their product, which maps $(x,y)$ to $f(x)g(x)$, is also continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tedious so I won't do it for you. But I will give you a hint on the one you mentioned.

Consider $|\frac{x^2 b-a^2y}{by}|$. The strategy is start by putting maximum bound on $\delta$. Often this is $\delta=1,$ but it's whatever is convenient. In this case, you are going to want to reduce the denominator to just a constant. If you obtain a lower bound on $|b||y|$, then that helps create an upper bound on the whole term.

For the numerator, the trick is to write
$$
x^2 b-a^2y \pm a^2b=(x^2-a^2)b-a^2(y-b)=(x-a)(x+a)b-a^2(y-b).
$$
Now, find an upper bound for the absolute value of this. Use the triangle inequality -- the bound doesn't need to be good. Also, use the fact that $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-b|<\delta$.

Comment: Thanks, I see, it that OK if I take |b||y|<2b, if assuming y is always grater than b?